# connect failed (111: Connection refused) reverse proxy using Nginx

Tags: django, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to revert ports to 8000 using docker, nginx and django but I get connection refused error. The docker build and compose works fine.
Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
    worker_processes auto;

    events {
    worker_connections 4;
    }

    http {
    upstream backend {
        # web is the docker-compose.yml backend service
        server web:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }
    }
```

and my docker-compose.yml file:

```
    services:
      db:
        image: postgres
        volumes:
          - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
          - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
        volumes:
          - .:/code
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
          - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        depends_on:
          - db
      nginx:
        image: nginx
        ports:
          - 80:80
        volumes:
          - ./nginx/config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        depends_on:
          - web
```

The error I'm getting:

```
`2023/10/28 08:22:33 [error] 22#22: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: my_pc_ip, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "127.0.0.1"`
```

I tried changing the nginx.conf and .yml file but nothing changed

Comment: change proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; 
this to 
proxy_pass http://backend;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it!
the problem was that the django wasn't running properly.
Iam now starting the server on Daphne AND thanks to 
[ABHAY KOTAL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10437248/abhay-kotal) for his comment, the final nginx.conf is:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    upstream backend {
        # web is the docker-compose.yml backend service
        server web:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 8001;
        # server_name 127.0.0.1;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }

}
```

That's it!